# Abort NSIS silent installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I've created an NSIS installer that installs a certain program. Everything works fine but I wonder if it is possible to abort the installation when it runs in silent mode.

So is there a way to abort an installation when I install an NSIS installer via the command line with this command: `installer.exe /S /D=Path/To/Directory`?

I tried to abort it via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as it works for other programs, too, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS is not a console program so it is not going to respond to console keyboard shortcuts.

Even if you could trick it into behaving like a console program when started silent it is not going to work in a stable manner because <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will just kill the process unless the program has added extra code to handle the aborting events...

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I thought... I'll just accept it that it's not easily possible to abort a silent NSIS installer.